# About continuous functions and continuous continuations and their uniqueness

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity, self-learning

How would you access the following problem:

> (a) Show that for every $s \in \mathbb{Q}$ the function $$f: \mathbb{C}^* \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$$ $$ f(z) := \frac{\overline z}{\vert z \vert ^s}$$ is continuous
>
> (b) for which $s \in \mathbb{Q}$ can we continuously continue $f$ in the origin? Is this continuation unique?

I'm pretty lost with this problem so im thankful for any kind of help and instruction thanks!

Answer (score 0):

(a) complex conjugation, absolute value, rational power, division are all continuous, hence so is $f$.

(b) Uniqueness is clear because $0$ is in the closure of $\mathbb C^\times$. For existence, consider cases $s>1$, $s=1$, $s<1$ separately.

Comment: what is actually $\mathbb{C}^*$?